# How to implement app purchase with sign in system?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have tow apps, the first one "hadeed" which is index for businesses, so each business have a channel (page) at "hadeed" app. this page describe the business details,show images ...

I have another app "hadeed manager" which used by the business owner , each user has a userName and password that sign with. with "hadeed manager" the business owner could change his business details(uploading images , change business location ...), then this updates will appear at "hadeed" app.

I want to charge the business owner when they updating details or uploading images using "hadeed manager". for example the user will pay 1 $ every month, then he can update his business details.

I've chose app purchase to charge business owners, the problem is that app purchase is associated with the apple id, so the bussines owner could login to business #1 and purchase the "hadeed manager" products, then log out from my system and log again to another business (in the same phone) and the storekit will show me that the user already purchase "hadeed manager" products.

How could I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like in-app purchases aren't what you want, then, if you are concerned with an Apple ID holder having multiple businesses or accounts on your service.

If you are committed to in-app purchases, perhaps you should go the way of non-renewing subscriptions as in-app purchases. For example, why not offer a $1.99 in-app purchase that is "one month of service", and more price points for longer periods of time. These purchases can be made as many times as the user desires, and each purchased asset is associated with a business entity in your service.

Otherwise, you may want to put management, subscription, and payment on a simple web application for your business owner users -- what's to say that every business owner owns an iOS device? You'd get more coverage of businesses by leveraging a neutral technology for their experience.

Comment: thank you for your response, actually I have a system that could charge the users, but I think I can't implement it at my ios app, because according to apple guide lines "Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected" so if I implement that using my system my app will not be accepted ! right ?

Comment: If you business model is such that you are, through some other system, inviting users to subscribe and share information, there is no Apple policy that says you can't write an app allowing those users to log in and manage their account. You're right in that it gets dicey when it comes to the exchanging of funds. I would make that functionality part of a web application -- your app should only be for already-registered users to manage their account. Look at apps like the Kindle app, for example -- you can't buy books in it but you can interact with the ones you've already paid for.

Comment: I've download kindle app, yes I couldn't create a user with the ios version, but I create it using the android version, and with android there is a possibility to buy a book using amazon system, not google play , but in ios I can't buy a book !